# How to insert 0 in the array returned by PDO query

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PDO query which return me the count of test-cases failed on a particular platform

```
$status = 'failed';
$allTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(testRunID),platform FROM tooldata WHERE status = :status GROUP BY platform ORDER BY platform' );
$allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status));
```

how i can modify this query, So that I can insert 0 for all those platform on which no test-case is failed.

I can check when the returned row is null with -

```
foreach($conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(testRunID),platform FROM tooldata WHERE status = :status GROUP BY platform ORDER BY platform') as $row):
    if($row['totalCOunt'] != 0):
        echo "WE HAVE Failed testcase";
    else:
        echo "WE DO NOT HAVE failed testcase";
    endif;
endforeach;
```

but how to insert 0 for such rows in the output array ?

Please help.

Comment: PDO has nothing to do with your question. you have to ask for pure SQL. Because you cannot get whatever zeros for the data you NEVER selected from DB. You have to explain in detail your data table structure and desired output, instead of posting some useless PDO code

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `WHERE` clause.
Try this...

```
SELECT COUNT(testRunID),platform FROM tooldata GROUP BY platform ORDER BY platform'
```

This query will show all the plateforms with respective count.

Comment: but i want to count only for failed testcases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your description, you may be need something like this

```
SELECT count(1), sum(if(status = 'failed'),1,0) platform 
FROM tooldata GROUP BY platform ORDER BY platform'
```

if it doesn't work for you - then don't complain, as I am not supposed to write a complete working code for you for free, but give you an idea, how to solve your problem. So - try to understand the idea, instead of just mindlessly copy/paste. And give some feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Use mysql `UNION` in your query to select other results :

```
SELECT 0, platform from tooldata where status != :status GROUP BY platform
    union select COUNT(testRunID),platform FROM tooldata WHERE status = :status GROUP BY platform ORDER BY platform
```

as such :

```
$status = 'failed';
$allTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT 0, platform from tooldata where status != :status GROUP BY platform
        union select COUNT(testRunID),platform FROM tooldata WHERE status = :status GROUP BY platform ' );
$allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status));
```

Comment: but I want to have the count of testcases failed as I want to render graph for the same.

Comment: This will give you all counts give it a shot.

Comment: it is returning the values of platform multiple times, as
**[15] => 0 [16] => 2530ya-24G  [219] => 64 [220] => 2530ya-24G**
How i can get platform only to appear once with the correct number ?
Like for the above two values the correct value for 2530ya-24G is 64.